can we say that the word "these" in the sentence does not carry a clear specification of the number of "best cities"
can we say that the word "these" in the sentence does not carry a clear specification of the number of "best cities"
"Of all the cities in the world I love New York, Chicago and Istanbul and these are the best."

I can say that I am making a double statement that I love three cities, and the number of "best cities" is essentially questionable, either two or all together

Try [elu.se] or [ell.se] for this kind of question.

I’m voting to close this question because is not about linguistics but English usage.
